# TMPro is a namespace but is used like a type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform player;
    public TMPro scoreText;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Debug.Log(player.position.z);
        scoreText.text = player.position.z.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: public TMPro scoreText; that's the faulty line. TMPro is the namespace containing the actual class. It should TextMeshPro or TextMeshProUGUI.

Comment: NullReferenceException: Obect reference not set to an instance of an object Score.Update () (at Assets/sCORE.CS:13) .  What i sould do now? Thank you!

Comment: _"NullReferenceException"_ - well that's a new question.  Please search SO before posting because it's a **very** popular question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the class inside this namespace. Use:
`public TMPro.TextMeshPro scoreText;`
Or
`public TextMeshPro scoreText;`

if you have already added the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TMPro.TMP_Text` for your field type.

`public TMPro.TMP_Text scoreText;`

It's a base class for all TMP text components.
BTW I'd make an extension for it in case it's null

```
public static class TextUtility
{
    public static void SetText(this TMPro.TMP_Text text, string value)
    {
        if (text)
            text.text = value;
    }
}
```

So you could do a `myText?.SetText("some text");` and if it is null or destroyed this wouldn't raise an error.

Comment: In case you didn't know, Extensions are cool. And Unity lacks some comfort features like this. I tend to add tons of them for all sorts of things like `myVector.Distance(anotherPoint);` instead of `Vector3.Distance(myVector, anotherVector);` this way it's more like a normal human readable text.

Comment: Using the null-propagation operator (?.) isn't necessary, since you have a null-check in the extension method anyways. (Extensions methods are still ran, even if the object is null)

Comment: Actually yeah! Nice catch. I feel I am doing this kind of fail-safe steps multiple times just for sanity. Just in case, I'll put this ? here. )))